# Mistake in recurrence relation text book?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm sorry for posting this here, but I would like to confirm my doubt about the correctness of the systems of equation in the textbook example. I enclosed an image.[image]

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  should be $+2C$.

Comment: Yeah it must be $2A+1=0$ and $3A-3B+2C=0$.

Comment: And the $2A-1$ is also wrong, should be $2A+1$.

Comment: I've never read a math textbook in my life that didn't have at least some typos.  And I've read many math textbooks, probably a hundred.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments!